# Mac Voiceover keyboard shortcuts works in safari but not in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility, voiceover, wcag, wcag2.0

I am having this issue in chrome. Some of the voiceover shortcut commands works in safari browser in Mac. But it doesn't work in chrome browser.

Example 
VO + P reads the paragraph in safari. But it does not work in chrome.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/dialog-modal/dialog.html

The above link is an w3 example. This same issue appears in that also.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking Safari is the only browser that fully works with VoiceOver. While you can do a lot of stuff in Chrome, you will likely run into these issues when trying with other browsers.